# how to get MySQL database URL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created a database in MySQL workbench and I want to get the URL of my database to use it in the JDBC code which is:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Database_URL, username, password);
```

so please tell how can I get Database_URL for my database???

Comment: How do you connect to your database otherwise?

Comment: By reading the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: type the ip address of your database...as other have asked, how do you connect to your database otherwise? :)